# URL is not getting typed in browser while loading Chrome with Extension in Node Machine in Selenium Grid Automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

While running Selenium Grid script on node with extension in chrome, the given URL is not getting typed in browser bar.

Test Condition: Below steps is been automated.

1. Open chrome browser with Multipass chrome extension on node.
2. Entering Extension Option html page in browser bar for filling some values in extension page.
3. Navigating to Test Application URL.

Output: Chrome is getting loaded in node machine with extension, but after that Extension option html page link URL is not getting typed in bar. Finally script get timed out exception.

- Selenium Server: Latest version
- Chrome Driver: 74…
- Chrome: 74..

Note Points: Script work fine if we make same machine as hub and node. Also the above script in node will work fine if we comment out the add extension statement in script.

Code:

```
public void Launch () {        
       //Setting capabilities as per the node         
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();                                                       
                           capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
                           capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);                               
                             ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions ();                                 
                            options.addArguments("start-maximized");
//Adding extension in chrome on node with CRX file of extension
       options.addExtensions (newFile("src\\test\\resources\\MultiPass-for-HTTP-basic-authentication_v0.8.4.crx"));              


                            options.merge(capabilities);
//opening driver with hub url details and capabilities options for node


                       driver = newRemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.141.108.84:4444/wd/hub"),options);                   


      wait = newWebDriverWait(driver,130);
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);           
     //opening the extension option html page for entering some values in shown page     
     driver.get("chrome-extension://enhldmjbphoeibbpdhmjkchohnidgnah/options.html");

}
```

Comment: Consider upgrading to chrome driver 75, seems to be there is some issue with 74.

Comment: @supputuri Any documentation/pointers towards _...some issue with 74..._?

Comment: Thank you for comment but as currently the latest stable version of chrome is 74 only so that how I can use 75 version of chrome driver. Please provide your input

Comment: You can download latest version (75) form [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). And the other option would be try with new profile (not default profile). Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session) to know how to work with profiles.

Comment: Thank you all for the response

Comment: Finally I got solution by using chrome 73 version and driver for same so the issue was with 74 version.