# Using user-data in selenium cause removing the extensions

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use an extension that needs a config, so I thought to configure it and put the user-data

I'm using python 3.7 on Windows 10

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=User/")
browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options = options)
```

I expect to open chrome with extensions, but when I run it, the folder user/default/extensions is empty (where they were the extensions)

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56402113#56402113) to know if you are pointing to the chrome profile correctly.

Comment: Yes Im using that

Comment: Have you loaded the extensions in that profile manually? or loading it as part of your script?

Comment: I added them in my browser then I copy the folder