# How to use default browser profile in Selenium instead of new one?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

I couldn't find any relevant answers and my question is pretty straight forward.

The context isn't really relevant.

It is very important for me that Selenium uses my normally installed browser (Chrome or Firefox), when doing coded things.

Comment: chromedriver by default uses your 'normally installed browser'. This is why it is essential for chromedriver and chrome versions to be correct. What do you mean by 'normal browser' instead of 'new instance'? Do you not want Selenium to start a new browser each time it runs?

Comment: You cannot use the default profile, but you can make a copy of it and set the driver options to use that profile when launching.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56402113#56402113)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe using your standard profile helps? It did in my case where the website was detecting the Selenium browser. This code solved my problem.

```
path = str(Path.home())
path = path + "/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx.default-release"
profile = FirefoxProfile(path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```