# Is there a way to have Selenium Webdriver launch my default Firefox browser instead of a clean version? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
bro = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Always opens a totally clean version of Firefox, with no history, bookmarks, nothing.
If it's not possible to launch my usual browser version, is it possible for me to launch it and then interact with it through Selenium?

Thanks all, first post here, tried my best to find answer but to no avail.

Comment: While I'm not sure about the extensions and whether you'll have to manually install them I could find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273428/how-to-use-default-browser-profile-in-selenium-instead-of-new-one) about loading the default profile

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen that one yet, seems like we have the same question. Tried similar code tho and what happens is the launch instruction takes a very long time, then launches geckodriver cmd and after a while launches still the same clean Firefox, not the one with my profile.