# How to use Chrome Profiles through Headless Chrome using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, chrome-profile

```
def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("user-data-dir=bot_data")
        options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
        options.add_argument('start-maximized') # 
        options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',
                                               options=options)
        self.driver.get('https://www.google.com')
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
```

There is have my codes. I want to change it to headless browser. But i am getting an error.

I added screenshot to show error.

[image: -- ERROR SCRENSHOOT --]

Comment: is this the whole code? The part that raises the error is the part that's trying to create some directories

Comment: I'm getting an error because of user-data thing. If its disabled then working. But i have to save login data.

Comment: Then, this isn't the part responsible for the error.

Comment: webdriver.Chrome is the line throwing the error.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(288)] Error writing DevTools active port to file
```

...implies that there was an error while writing *DevTools active port* to the required file.

As per the discussion in [How to open a Chrome Profile through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195) instead of specifying only the *directory* name through `user-data-dir`, you need to pass the *absolute path* of the `user-data-dir`.

---

### Solution

So you need to replace the line of code:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=bot_data")
```

With:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\bot_data")
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3/52399027#52399027)
- [Selenium: Point towards default Chrome session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56401979#56401979)

---

### Outro

A couple of relevant documentations:

- [Session isolation in Headless Chrome](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XAKvrxtSEoe65vNghSWC5S3kJ--z2Zpt2UWW1Fi8GiM/edit?pref=2&pli=1#heading=h.7r3ycehq63g2)
- [headless: Introduce a browser context](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/25c2c0123425d8ab3c9c02998d02d7accd1c42e2)
- [Save and restore browser sessions](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617931)
- [Headless maintains a different profile folder structure to headful](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775703)

Comment: Okay, i will try it. But how can i run it with multiple accounts if i change the location of user-data ?

Comment: The os.path.abspath on my user-data-dir option was my only change and it fixed the issue.