# Selenium is not loading a website but desktop browser loads

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I was trying to scrape a [website](https://shop.coles.com.au/a/aspley/product/mutti-tomato-passata-2349503p) using selenium web driver. But my automated browser doesn't load the website, I've also tried to load it manually opening a new tab but failed to load only shows blank page but my desktops chrome loads the website fine. I don't get it why the automated browser doesn't load the page.

```py
class SeleniumScrapper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://shop.coles.com.au/a/aspley/product/mutti-tomato-passata-2349503p'
        self.path = '/home/shanto/Software/ChromeDriver/chromedriver'
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(self.path)
        self.browser.get(self.url)
```

Inspection from chrome developer tools sents one [request](https://shop.coles.com.au/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint) status code 404
[image]

Comment: Check if there are any cookies or policies that are required to access the application. If you want to launch chrome your default chrome profile visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56402113#56402113)

Comment: If there is any response received from the server? What is the response code?

Comment: @AlexeyR. from the inspection section found that sends a request name fingerprint gets status code 404. Please check updated question