# How to start Chrome headless with user-data-dir flag with ChromeDriver version 83.0.4103.39 and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-profile

**Code**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArguments("--headless");
options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArguments("--disable-software-rasterizer");
options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=/profiles/" + profile);
options.AddArguments("--disable-software-rasterizer");
options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920x1080");
options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArguments("--disable-plugins-discovery");

IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"someUrl"); ---> Here code stucks
```

**Error:**

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote
> WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:64225/session timed out
> after 60 seconds.'

**I also tried**

```
options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
```

**Console output**

```
"A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at 
<SomeSite> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. 
A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies 
with cross-site requests if they are set with 
`SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies 
in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies 
and see more details at 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", 
source: <someURL> (0)
```

Comment: What is the value of `profile`?

Comment: Always same, just string, like "Alex"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:64225/session timed out after 60 seconds.
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session using the desired [*Chrome Profile*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195).

As per the discussion in [How to open a Chrome Profile through --user-data-dir argument of Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211) instead of specifying only the *directory* name through `user-data-dir`, you need to pass the *absolute path* of the `user-data-dir`.

---

### Solution

So you need to replace the line of code:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=bot_data")
```

With:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\bot_data")
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3/52399027#52399027)
- [Selenium: Point towards default Chrome session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56401979#56401979)

---

### Outro

A couple of relevant documentations:

- [Session isolation in Headless Chrome](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XAKvrxtSEoe65vNghSWC5S3kJ--z2Zpt2UWW1Fi8GiM/edit?pref=2&pli=1#heading=h.7r3ycehq63g2)
- [headless: Introduce a browser context](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/25c2c0123425d8ab3c9c02998d02d7accd1c42e2)
- [Save and restore browser sessions](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617931)
- [Headless maintains a different profile folder structure to headful](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775703)

Comment: Thanks Very much!! The thing is that without --headless option, the application works with incorrect user-data-dir, how is it possible? Is it using default (coz the cookie really same)?
It can be seen that you are professional in Selenium, could you look please on options, are all of them are necessary for headless chrome? 
no-sandbox, headless, disable-gpu, disable-dev-shm-usage
I'm using it on windows.
Really appreciate your answer