# Selenium python - How to load Default Chrome Profile

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-profile

I need to load my own ***Default*** chrome profile where all my saved login info is, instead of selenium logging me into my websites.

I have taken this code from stackoverflow, cannot find the exact user. My issue with this code is selenium opens chrome but does not load the correct profile. Every time I open run the code it creates a new "scoped_dir" folder and runs the profile "default" from there [chrome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbJWw.png)
(C:\Users\farja\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir[bunch of numbers]\Default).

I have tried closing chrome and then running my code which doesn't work

I am thinking there is a big flaw in my code but do not know what it is or how to find it. A relevant answer for 2022 would be very very much appreciated as I have literally been stuck on this for a week now and have tried multiple answers on stackoverflow, the web and youtube but nearly all give me a deprecation error.

Thank you for taking the time to read.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

ser = Service(r'C:\Users\farja\Documents\Instagram Programmes\Scheduler 2\chromedriver')
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
s = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)

op.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\farja\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
op.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
s.get("chrome://version/")
```

Answer (score 0):

As your usecase is to load the [*Default Chrome Profile*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3/52399027#52399027) you can use the argument [`user-data-dir`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56401979#56401979)  and remove the argument `--profile-directory` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\farja\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
ser = Service(r'C:\Users\farja\Documents\Instagram Programmes\Scheduler 2\chromedriver')
s = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)
s.get("chrome://version/")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to open a Chrome Profile through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195)
- [How to open a Chrome Profile through --user-data-dir argument of Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211)