# Chromdriver UserData configuration with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-profile

I have this simple function with Selenium

```py
def config():
    path = r'C:\Users\George\Desktop\Bot\User Data'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('user-data-dir=' + path)
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\George\Desktop\Bot\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
    return driver
```

Which is working fine and as expected, But am making a simple bot to do tasks over a website that require sessions and cookies and so on.

So what I have to make each now and then, Is to copy the real browser User Data from:

```
C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

to my random location

```
'C:\Users\George\Desktop\Bot\User Data'
```

And it works fine, The reason am doing this is that I want to avoid login, and have the browser that I work with independent with the bot driver browser, And I Usually keep it laid down and never open while its doing my work.

**Question**

- Is there a way, That I can automatically get the current session instant of copying Files (like get one open tab with all information attached )?
- Is there a better way to do this? ( am sure there are plenty of better ways)

Thanks for the help, Any suggestion, Links, Blogs are much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be required to copy the real browser *User Data* from:

```
C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

to:

```
C:\Users\George\Desktop\Bot\User Data
```

each now and then if you point *`user-data-dir`* to the real [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *User Data* directory as follows:

```
def config():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # next line you need to replace the random location with actual browser data location
    options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") 
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\George\Desktop\Bot\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
    return driver
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Selenium: Point towards default Chrome session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401979/7429447)